# Javascript fetch(POST) to express server fails. The server does not receive the request from JS, but receives request from Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, fetch

**MRE** -> [node-server](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/node-server) : [react app](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/react-form)

---

When I send a POST request using Postman, I get the expected result. This is the request that I am sending using Postman

[image]

and `test sent` gets printed to the console of my node server

If I send a request from my react form however, `test sent` does not print to the console, but the `catch` block of my fetch request get's executed and `err` is printed to the console of my react app, followed by `{}`.

I would like to know why my POST request is not working and is not getting received by the server

---

Below is the function that I call when someone clicks the submission button of my form created in react

**Function called on form submission**

```
nodeUrl = 'https://localhost:6060?'

const submitData = async () => {

    fetch(nodeUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({'test': 'test'})
    }).then((res) => {
      alert('then')
    }).catch((err) => {
      alert('err')
      alert(JSON.stringify(err))
    })
  }
}
```

This is the server that I run using `node server.js`

**server.js**

```
server.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('test sent')    
    mailer.messages().send(req.body)
    .then((mes) => {
        console.log(mes)
        res.json({ message: 'Thanks for your message. Our service team has been notified and will get back to you shortly.' })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.json(err);
    })
});
```

Comment: You define `nodeUrl`, but are trying to access it via a property on the `data` object. Could this be your problem?

Comment: @camwhite Sorry, I changed it in here, that's not the problem, I was just trying to make this post easier to read. Everything else is basically identical

Comment: What error do you see in the console of your browser? Does is say something related to "Cross Origin" or CORS request? You can also try updating the **nodeUrl** variable to replace that last **?** with "/".

Comment: It says `err` because of the `alert('err')` and then when I alert the `err` object I see `{}`

Comment: You will see complete detail in the Network tab of the developer tool. Select the XHR tab under the filter section.

Comment: @Sam please check the API with HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS. The correct value for nodeUrl should be **http://localhost:6060**.

Comment: @SujitKumarSingh Thanks, that fixed part of the problem, I sent you more images in the chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majour issue here is due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). [CORS support](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) can be used to overcome this. Just keep in mind to have this only for development mode(see below codes).

But, as per the Postman's snapshot and provided GitHub repositories, the request from Front-end should be of `multipart/form-data` type. Thus, the Front-end code would look like this

```
const nodeUrl = "http://localhost:6060/";

const submitData = async () => {
  // create a FormData object
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('form', 'example@email.com');
  formData.append('to', 'example@email.com');

  // this auto adds 'multipart/form-data' + HASH header in the request
  fetch(nodeUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
  })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Error -', err);
    });
};
```

To handle **multipart/form-data** request in the ExpressJS, you need a plugin [Multer](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html).

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer  = require('multer'); // for 'multipart' type request
const server = express();
const upload = multer();

// allow CORS requests in development mode
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // Server run command - "NODE_ENV=development node server.js"
  const cors = require('cors');
  server.use(cors());
}

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// using Multer middleware form extracting 'FormData' payload
server.post('/', upload.none(), function(req, res) {
  console.log('Received body', req.body);
  ... // other codes
});
```

**Strategy 2(plain JSON) -**

If that 'multipart/form-data' strategy was unintentional and you just want to send simple JSON, use below codes -

In Front-end, trigger API request as -

```
fetch(nodeUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', // this needs to be defined
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ from: 'some@email.com', to: 'other@email.com' })
})
```

In server, just ignore codes related to Multer and only keep your API as -

```
server.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Received body', req.body);
  ... // other codes
});
```

Comment: What is a method that would work in production mode?

Comment: Do you know a resource where I could learn a little more about this, that's really dumbed down or split in jot notes or diagrams?

Comment: In production, the static files(HTML, JS and CSS) will be under the root domain. There the requests would by default come from the same origin. There wouldn't be any issue related to the CORS request.

Comment: @Sam found [Mozilla's doc with graphical representation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and a [technical explanation and solution blog](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/dealing-with-cors-in-create-react-app).
However, I am still waiting for your confirmation that it is really a CORS issue. If it is not then my answer would be irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: I tried `const cors = require('cors');` and `server.use(cors)` inside my `server.js`, as well as included `  "proxy": "http://localhost:6060"` inside my `package.json` in my React app and get the same results

Comment: @Sam Please have a look at the API response under the Network tab. This will clarify our doubts regarding the actual issue.

Comment: `websocket 101 websocket sockjs.js:1684 0 B Pending`
`localhost (failed) fetch index.jsx:93 0 B 4 ms`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222322/discussion-between-sujit-kumar-singh-and-sam).

Comment: This solution, in addition to the fetch request that I posted in my answer lead to a working solution

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a better fetch request, which was put together for me by selecting `code -> Javascript Fetch` in Postman(under the save button)

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("from", "example@email.com");
urlencoded.append("test", "test");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http:localhost:6060/, requestOptions)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok){
      response.json().then(json => {
        console.log(json)
      })
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('error: ', error))
```